# PHP Google Sheets API - Permission Denied

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, permission-denied, google-sheets-api

Hi I've just started to study PHP and I'm attempting to use the Google sheets API.

I thought I followed their instructions and I could call and edit sheet data well but only Public Access.

When I change access status as private or Group, I encounter message below.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

And I will put my codes what you would see to help.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
        Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS)
));

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.CREDENTIALS_PATH);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

$client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);

$tokenArray = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
$accessToken = $tokenArray["access_token"];

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

$spreadsheetId = "1qe7QwyYxWuIAYT7UUZ2s3KdDZrAHJ02uPH4VPrr-pMk";

$range = "Sheet1";
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
if (count($values) == 0) {
    print "No data found.\n";
}
print_r($values);
```

Is there anything to confirm in the code? or google API console?

Any information would be greatly appreciated! thanks in advance!

Comment: if the user you are authenticated as doesn't have access to the file then you wont be able to write to the file.  You must always have permissions to access private user data.   By setting it public you are saying that anyone can write to it.  But setting it private or group only the owner or members of the group will be able to write to it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But the thing is I've created sheet document and credential in console using my email and account. So the my account is owner of all permissions and the OAuth. anything to check more about permissions?

Comment: If you are authorizing your php app (loging in yes access my data)  with the same account as owns the file I would check the file id it should work.

Comment: Can you go to File->Share->Advanced and check in the Sharing settings if your email is set as the owner? Also, I am assuming that you're access token did not expire.

Comment: After add API's service account (blah@blahblah.iam.gserviceaccount.com) in my sheet sharing setting, it works well.. :( Thank you for helping to find my issues. And I don't need the key "client_secret.json" anymore. is it correct way?

Answer (score 1):

File->Share->Advanced and add the service account

eg: `your@email.iam.gserviceaccount.com`